# Variable Argument List

Tags: java

My code keeps returning zero as the result regardless of what I type in. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class VariableArgumentList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(product(2,2,2));

}
public static int product(int...integers) {//method product using an elipse
    int product = 0;//set product to zero
    for (int x:integers)//enhanced for loop, sets integer to x that takes integers
        product *= x;//loop through entered integers, multiply them and store product in variable x

    return product*integers.length;//setting return for method product
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be 2 * 2 * 2 = 8. The output I'm getting is zero.

Comment: Change `int product = 0;` to `int product = 1;` Zero works for sum nut not for product.

Comment: Now it returned 24 which can't be right either.

Comment: @RileyHall 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 and 8 * 3 = 24

Comment: You multiply it by length - which is 3.

Comment: Well why would anyone want to do that? How do I multiply them by each other instead of the length?

Comment: @RileyHall if you don't want the return value to be multiplied by the length of the array, then maybe don't multiply the result by the length of the array before returning it.

Comment: Yep, I'm officially lost.

Comment: I got it. I just needed to `int product = 1` & `return product;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(product(2, 2, 2, 2));

    }

    public static int product(int... integers)
    {// method product using an elipse
        int product = 1;// set product to zero
        for (int x : integers)// enhanced for loop, sets integer to x that takes integers
            product *= x;// loop through entered integers, multiply them and store product in variable x

        return product ;// setting return for method product
    }
```